# asset_path not prepending application name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So I have a Rails 3.1 application.  In one of the template files (index.html.erb) I have this:

```
<%= image_tag('resource_icons/entitlements.png') %>
```

which produces:

```
<img alt="Entitlements" src="/intl-custserv-web/assets/resource_icons/entitlements-e77a9dbcdfe3b5bdc5e1f3c3e373a0a7.png" />
```

And in a CSS file (dock.css.erb) I have this:

```
background-image:url(<%= asset_path("resource_icons/favorite-customers-icon-small.png"))
```

But this produces:

```
background-image:url(/assets/resource_icons/favorite-customers-icon-small-613656faee70881de686d4524504a1e2.png)
```

I need the asset_path tag to prepend the application name the same way that image_tag does.  Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your environment config (ex: config/enivorments/production.rb) add this line with the correct path for your application:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/application_name'
```

Comment: That results in a RackInitializationException "relative_url_root= method not found".  I also tried the suggestions here [https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3365](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3365) , but this has not worked either.  This is the command I'm using to generate the assets: `jruby -S bundle exec rake assets:precompile` .  I've tried it with and without the RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT parameter.

Comment: Ok, so in the link I posted in the last comment, I didn't realize that pokonski's patch wasn't included with the latest version of Rails.  So I went in to actionpack and made the edit that he described, and then using the RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT parameter with the rake assets:precompile command works.  <sigh>  I wonder if his fix will be included with the next release?

Comment: So @JohnColvin, your solution works great after an upgrade to Rails 3.2.  Using that solution now, thanks!